# Spring Oauth2 resource server skip swagger URL - Open API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openapi

I need help in skipping the swagger URL from security configuration. I tried every solution out there in stackoverflow. Below is my current configuration. I am getting 401 when trying to open the swagger URL

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
};


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
       cors().disable().csrf().disable().
       authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
}}
```

Below is my OpenAPI configuration

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = { @Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL") })
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application-description") String appDesciption,
            @Value("${application-version:1.0.0}") String appVersion) {

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setEmail("www.abc.com");
        contact.setName("abc");
        return new OpenAPI()

                .info(new Info()

                        .title("ABC Cloud Application API")

                        .version(appVersion)

                        .description(appDesciption)

                        .contact(contact));

    }

}
```

> I am using spring-boot version 2.5.8 and open API version
> springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.13

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In tomcat we need to add **WebSecurity**

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
  "help/**", "swagger**", "swagger-resources/**", "v2/**", "webjars/**"
```

};

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, AUTH_WHITELIST);
```

}

Comment: After adding websecurity also, I was getting the 401 error. I was using multi- module project and had the spring security configuration in comman base module. Moving the security to individual module solved the issue. Not sure why this was happening.